# PYTHONPATH in .bashrc? .profile? Errors when upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to 18

Tags: python3, bashrc, anaconda

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 18.10 from 1, and now I am having problems with some of my settings. I used Anaconda python, and when trying to load one of my custom libraries, I get this:

```
---> 13 from meta_utilities import feature_processing as fp

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meta_utilities'
```

I run this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

which returns this:

```
['', '/home/luis/Documents/kaggle', '/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/luis/.ipython']
```

However, when I do echo $PYTHONPATH, it returns empty

The repo where I have my python development files is

```
/home/luis/Documents/
```

I have added several variations of this to .profile, bash.bashrc, .bashrc and after sourcing, I can't get to set my pythopath..

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/luis/Documents/"
export PYTHONPATH=/home/luis/Documents/
export PYTHONPATH="/home/luis/Documents/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

No idea why none of these variations work. Is there a "hidden" bashrc used by Anaconda that overrides settings? Why echo $PYTHONPATH reports empty and sys reports something? Where is the bashrc file that sys is reading to report what it reports?

Comment: try to add it on `/etc/environment` with including `VAR=/path/to/bin/of/python3:/path/to/lib/of/python3:/path/to/include/of/python3` and  to echo again

Comment: That sounds impractical: I have hundreds of python libraries installed to go over one by one

Comment: you try to add it with `$HOME` directory even though `$PYTHONHOME` have secure_path included on `$PATH ` variable. i'm not sure if it work. try to copy your libraries on `$PATH` defined.

Comment: What is $PYTHONHOME?????

Comment: you can see it with `man python`

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like guess work and moving away from an effective solution of my problem.

Comment: if you want try it on `.bashrc` file. try to run `echo "export VAR=/your/path" >> ~/.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc` and call echo again